# System.Exception+ExceptionMessageKind.OutOfMemory in Xamarin form IOS how to handle?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

System.Exception+ExceptionMessageKind.OutOfMemory  when I clicked on button for recording audio how to   handle and how to extend memory in IOS I read many articles but all related Android no one is clearly about IOS  ? this may code its worked fine in android but not for IOS all permissions set for audio recorder like microphone and memory.

```
        ` private async void bntRecord_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        try
        {
            if (!recorder.IsRecording)
            {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes = 0;
                isTimerRunning = true;
                Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
                {
                    seconds++;

                    if (seconds.ToString().Length == 1)
                    {
                        lblSeconds.Text = "0" + seconds.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblSeconds.Text = seconds.ToString();
                    }
                    if (seconds == 60)
                    {
                        minutes++;
                        seconds = 0;

                        if (minutes.ToString().Length == 1)
                        {
                            lblMinutes.Text = "0" + minutes.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lblMinutes.Text = minutes.ToString();
                        }

                        lblSeconds.Text = "00";
                    }
                    return isTimerRunning;
                });
                recorder.StopRecordingOnSilence = IsSilence.IsToggled;
                var recordTask = await recorder.StartRecording();
                bntRecord.IsEnabled = false;
                bntRecord.BackgroundColor = Color.Silver;
                bntPlay.IsEnabled = false;
                bntPlay.BackgroundColor = Color.Silver;
                bntStop.IsEnabled = true;
                bntStop.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#7cbb45");
                await recordTask;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: which specific line causes the exception?